# Can't use FitBounds on React Google Map

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

Even if there're several questions about this, I can't find the solution in them. Here's why:
I made a Google Maps component from react-google-maps in npm. The render of that component show this:

```
render() {
return (this.state.skipRender && "Bad Addresses") || (
  <Map      
    google={this.props.google}
    initialCenter={this.state.center}
    bounds={this.state.bounds}
  >
    {this.displayMarkers()}
  </Map>
);
```

}

I want to put a fitBound, to make all markers generated in displayMarkers to be visible within the viewport. But there's nowhere I can use fitbounds. If I put it as a part of properties of  nothing happens. If I try to use map.fitBounds it says "map" is undefined. How I should apply fitBounds?

Just in case is necessary, here's the displayMarkers function:

```
  displayMarkers = () => {
return this.state.skipRender || this.state.addresses.map((address, index) => {
  return <Marker
    key={index}
    id={index}
    position={{
      lat: address.lat,
      lng: address.lng
    }}
    title={this.state.titles[index]}
  />
});
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are utilizing [`google-maps-react` library](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react), right?

If so, `Map` component invokes `Map.fitBounds` method [internally](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/blob/master/src/index.js) if `bounds` prop is passed.

Here is an example how make markers to be visible within the viewport:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

const locations = [
  { Id: 1, name: "Oslo", lat: 59.923043, lng: 10.752839 },
  { Id: 2, name: "Stockholm", lat: 59.339025, lng: 18.065818 },
  { Id: 3, name: "Copenhagen", lat: 55.675507, lng: 12.574227 },
  { Id: 4, name: "Berlin", lat: 52.521248, lng: 13.399038 },
  { Id: 5, name: "Paris", lat: 48.856127, lng: 2.346525 }
];

class MapExample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bounds: null
    };
    this.handleMapLoad = this.handleMapLoad.bind(this)
  }

  handleMapLoad() {
    const bounds = new this.props.google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (let loc of locations) bounds.extend({ lat: loc.lat, lng: loc.lng });
    this.setState({bounds:bounds});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Map
        onReady={this.handleMapLoad}
        className={"map"}
        google={this.props.google}
        zoom={5}
        initialCenter={{ lat: 48.1327673, lng: 4.1753323 }}
        bounds={this.state.bounds}
      >
        {locations.map((loc, i) => (
          <Marker key={i} position={{ lat: loc.lat, lng: loc.lng }} />
        ))}
      </Map>
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "--your key goes here--"
})(MapExample);
```

> Note: `onReady` event is triggered once the map is loaded

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the correct `center`and `zoom` manually. For that you may want to use the [utility function `fitBounds`](https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/API.md#fitbounds-func):

```
import { fitBounds } from 'google-map-react/utils';

const bounds = {
  nw: {
    lat: 50.01038826014866,
    lng: -118.6525866875
  },
  se: {
    lat: 32.698335045970396,
    lng: -92.0217273125
  }
};

const size = {
  width: 640, // Map width in pixels
  height: 380, // Map height in pixels
};

// use these to re-render your map
const {center, zoom} = fitBounds(bounds, size);
```

Comment: It doesn't find 'google-map-react/utils', but 'google-map-react'. And I get Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Object(...) is not a function in the function where I include this line: const {center, zoom} = fitBounds(bounds, size);